# Thunderbird (Google) calendar entries disappearing

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar

Intermittently, all events from (Google) calendars disappear from Thunderbird. The affected calendar is still listed in TB, but with no events.

Unsubscribing then re-subscribing to the affected calendar solves the problem, BUT it takes several minutes for TB to "find" calendars in the requested Google account.

Any suggestions for solving this?

Thunderbird 102.2.2 (64-bit) in Ubuntu 22.04 package.
Not using any calendar addons for Google calendar.
Other addons are CardBook, Emoji, & FileLink Provider for DropBox.

Comment: Which Thunderbird add-ons are you using?

Comment: After the upgrade to Thunderbird 102, I have to use https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/ Without this add-on I am not able to access my Google Calendar from Thunderbird.

Comment: How odd. Apart from the intermittent problem above, I have been syncing both ways without any calendar add-on. Perhaps TB is getting access to Google calendar via the CardBook add-on, which is syncing my Google contacts.  Anyway, I've added Provider for Google Calendar.